# Bind event to multiple jquery elements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I need to bind the same event (for example `click`) to *n* jquery elements. I know I can achieve this result easily with a selector:

```
$("#first, #second, .third").on("click", function(){});
```

but what if, instead of a selector, I want to use a list of jquery elements?

This is the solution I'm using right now, assume you get `$first` and `$second` as a result of a function:

```
var $first = $("#first");
var $second = $("#second");

$([$first[0], $second[0]]).on("click", function(){
    alert("click " + this.innerText)
});
```

find fiddle to play with here: https://jsfiddle.net/0z2r55d6/

as you can see I need to extract, for each jquery element, the HTML element and push it into an array. I find this pretty ugly and unhandy.. Is there a better way to achieve the same result? I didn't find anything in jquery's documentation.

Thanks

Comment: `$first.add($second).add($third).on('click', handler);` Or use a common class instead

Comment: @A.Wolff That worked like a charm, thanks. Please answer with your solution so I can accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, i was quite busy, no time for making a relevant answer. You should accept Apul's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery [add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$first.add($second).add($third).on('click', handler);
```